# Attempting to resolve dependency 'Transformer.NET (≥ 2.1.1)'. Install-Package : '2.1.1-PREVIEW' is not a valid version string

Tags: ext.net

when trying to install like this `PM> Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC` ,I am getting this error.

error detail:

```
PM> Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Ext.NET.Utilities (≥ 2.4.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Transformer.NET (≥ 2.1.1)'.
Install-Package : '2.1.1-PREVIEW' is not a valid version string.
Parameter name: version
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I have already update package manager console.

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.50313.31
I am using VS 2012,project I have created mvc 4
```

*I also tried to install like this but same result:  `PM> Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC4`

**UPDATE**

after installed transformer,and try to attempt install Mvc4 ,I am getting an error something like this

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'Ext.Net'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC4
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: I just tried Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC on VS 2012 and the same version of NuGet as yours and it is unstalled correctly for me. Hard to say what is going wrong. Are you installing Ext.NET.MVC on a clear project? I mean clear from previous versions of Ext.NET. If Ext.NET is already installed, please try to uninstall first.

Comment: Yep it worked ,after create a new project,and installed Transformer.NET first,I was able to install,thanks

Comment: Ok, then I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes such problems happen if install a new package over an old package. Please try to reinstall first:

```
Uninstall-Package Ext.NET.MVC
```

Then install again

```
Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC
```